# Trying to convert a list of scraped values to Pandas DataFrame in Python. df = DataFrame (your_list,columns=['Name']) only takes text and not full str

Tags: python, html, pandas, dataframe, web-scraping

I have a list with scraped values like:

```
[<a href="shropshire.html">A Shropshire Lad (David Austin Rose, Austin, 1997) </a>,
 <a href="agiraud.html">Abbé Giraudier (Hybrid Perpetual, Levet, 1869)</a>,
 <a href="abelcarr.html">Abel Carrière (Hybrid Perpetual, E. Verdier, 1875)</a>,
 <a href="abelc.html">Abel Carrière (Illustration from <em>Le Livre d'Or des Roses</em>, 1903)</a>,
 <a href="darby.html">Abraham Darby® (David Austin Rose, Austin, 1985)</a>,
 <a href="adammes.html">Adam Messerich (Hybrid Bourbon, Lambert, 1920)<br/>
 </a>,
```

When I convert my list to a pandas DataFrame only text appears in the column and not the full value.

[image]

How do I make a df with the full content of each `<a> ... </a>,`? Or how can I get a df with two columns one with href and another with text?

Comment: The problem is with the data you've scraped. You've actually scraped the entire <a> tag rather than the href attribute and <a> tag text seperately. So pandas is taking this entire <a> and putting inside one column. Some more code from the web scraping perspective would help. You can specify columns using pandas.DataFrame (data, columns=['links','text'] )

Comment: @AaronS I know that I am not doing scraping ideal way. I can try and fix the issue by fixing scraping, but this question is about unexpected behaviour of Pandas. I am trying to figure out why it did not take the full scraped string with <a> tags as expected. My plan was to convert it into column and then extract href and text into separate columns. 

Will add now in the description my scraping code.

Comment: My point is that the your dictionary is being intepreted by python as one column with many rows. You're far better seperating concerns before inputting to pandas. I'm not even sure you can parse the <a> tag using pandas.

Comment: @AaronS Will change my scraping code as advised.

Comment: @AaronS I fixed the scraping code, it now does what I want it to do. If you are interested my notebook is saved on GitHub - https://github.com/anna-zverkova/Rose_scrape/blob/master/Rosegathering_scrape.ipynb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting the answer here for other developers.

You need to extract the href and text from  tag

typically something like

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text,'lxml')
with open(filename,'w',newline='',encoding='utf-8') as f:
    w = csv.writer(f)
    for a in soup.find_all('a',href=True):
        text = a.text
        link = a['href']
        w.writerow([text,link])
```

Then you could load this CSV into pandas like so.

```
pandas.read_csv('filename.csv', columns =['text','url'])
```

Comment: This is exactly what I did. :)
@AaronS thanks for posting for other developers.

Comment: Could you tick the answer at the left hand side as the accepted one if you think it's helpful to others ?

Comment: @AsronS ticked as requested.